# How to pass static data from route config to components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to pass static data from route to component. I tried passing the data in the route config but I get empty data when I subscribe data from the activatedRoute. I have provided my code below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from '../../app.component';
import { CompanyInformationComponent } from '../../components/pages/company/company-information/company-information.component';
import { CompanyDescriptionComponent } from '../../components/pages/company/company-description/company-description.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', redirectTo: 'company-information', pathMatch: 'full', data: { title: 'Company Information' } },
  { path:'company-information', component: CompanyInformationComponent, data: { title: 'Company Information' } },
  { path:'company-description', component: CompanyDescriptionComponent, data: { title: 'Company Description' } },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [

  ]
})
export class routingModule { }
```

My header component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'site-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private route:ActivatedRoute ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('Title',data);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get data using `route.snapshot.data`

You should also inject `Router` to watch for `router.events`, so that constructor will look like

```
constructor (private router : Router, private route : ActivatedRoute) {}
```

and in OnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .subscribe(
            () => {
                console.log(this.route.snapshot.data) // should print { title: 'Company Information'}
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, tried this code and getting this error "this.router.events.filter is not a function"

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? And Have you imported `Router` and `ActivatedRoute` properly?

Comment: using angular 5, and also injected router, activatedRoute and tried importing filter from rxjs, but still getting empty object

Comment: Then it seems like `router.events` inside HeaderComponent is never invoked. Try to log inside that event to verify if it is ever triggered or not.
If this is true, then you have to subscribe for `router.event` at different place.

Comment: And also you are trying to fetch data in `HeaderComponent` where as activated component is `CompanyInformationComponent`. That could be an issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass values through the routing like this :

example : `path: 'company-information/:valueToPass',`

And in your component :

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

[...]

constructor( protected route: ActivatedRoute){
 this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      if (params.valueToPass) {
        this.localValue= params.valueToPass;
      }
    });
}
```